# How to access object parent in D

Tags: oop, d

Say I have a class, `Master`, that starts up my program, and I have another class, `TerminalIO`, that has functions and data for talking to stdin and stdout. I then instantiate a `Master` object from `main()`.

In code within the methods of `TerminalIO`, how would I access the properties and functions of `Master`?

The reason I'm asking about this is because my program needs to store some shared data (both enums and regular variables), and I was wanting to know of an efficient way to do that. I'm not so sure this is the best way, but it's certainly better than toying with the `package` keyword and trying to store "global" data at module level or whathaveyou.

I think it's worth noting that I will have many other objects that also want access to this shared data, so a simple reference may not be the best of ideas.

Comment: `Master` is sounding like it could become a god object. Check your design; can you not pass in the values that `TerminalIO` needs when constructing it?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get a reference to Master inside your TerminalIO.

There are a couple of ways you could use:

1. Have Master be a singleton, so there is only one instance which you can access with Master.instance, so you'll have something like Master.instance.masterProperty.
2. Having a TerminalIO factory method in Master which constructs a TerminalIO and passes a Master reference to the constructor.